# What is the 'value' parameter of Sequelize's Model.update() supposed to look like?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm on Sequelize v4, and I'm trying to update a single attribute in a single record with [update](https://sequelize.org/v4/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-update).  I'm not understanding how the 'values' object is supposed to look, and I can't find any documentation regarding it.

My assumption was that it would be {columnName: updatedValue}, as such:

```js
Model.update(
  {columnToUpdate: valueToUpdate},
  {
    where: {...},
    fields: ['columnToUpdate']
  }
)
```

The where clause is working as intended, but the result I'm getting is only applying SET to 'updatedAt', like so:

```
UPDATE `tableToUpdate` SET `updatedAt`='2020-08-21 20:50:22' WHERE `userId` = '123' AND `id` = '456'
```

I can't find any documentation that provides an example for what Sequelize is looking for as far as the value parameter is concerned.

Comment: Why do use fields property?

Comment: I tried it with and without the fields property - no change.

Answer (score 1):

In the example I didn't see them use the `fields` for a model. Though it does look like it's the right syntax.

Example from docs:

```
Task.update(
    { status: 'inactive' },
    { where: { subject: 'programming' }}
  );
```

docs: https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/instances.html

Comment: Thanks for finding that in the docs and sharing it with me.  I wonder why what I'm trying isn't working.
Edit:  Ah - actually that's called on an instance, and I'm trying to perform a query on a Model.